# Can not access local network through devices connected through wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, lan

I have a D-Link DSL-2750U ADSL router (Firmware version: IN_1.08).

I have 4 devices connected with following IPs:

- Router (10.0.0.1)
- WireConnected1 (10.0.0.4)
- WireConnected2 (10.0.0.5)
- WirelessConnected1 (10.0.0.6)
- WirelessConnected2 (10.0.0.7)

All 4 devices can connect to Internet. However, if I have a web server running on port `80` on `WireConnected1`, and I try to browse `http://10.0.0.4/`, I can only access it through `WireConnected1` and `WireConnected2`, and I can not access `http://10.0.0.4/` through `WirelessConnected1` and `WirelessConnected2`.

It's like local server can only be accessed through devices connected through Ethernet and not through devices connected through Wi-Fi.

What settings could affect such situation? I thoroughly checked all settings in router's web-interface but couldn't find any anomalies.

Comment: My first guess would be AP-isolation. I don't know D-Link WLAN routers and know the exact option name, but look for something that says that wireless clients shall not see other clients.

Comment: @bjanssen, there is a "User Isolation" option is wireless settings but it is set to "off".

Comment: @bjanssen, the problem was that "Enable MultiAP Isolation" was checked (in Setup -> Wireless -> Wireless Basic) which was blocking cross access/ping. If you copy your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess would be AP-isolation. I don't know D-Link WLAN routers and know the exact option name, but look for something that says that wireless clients shall not see other clients.

Comment: And the problem was that "Enable MultiAP Isolation" was checked (in Setup -> Wireless -> Wireless Basic) which was blocking cross access/ping.

Answer (score 0):

For me an additional step was required

```
Advanced > Advanced Wireless > Mac Filtering
```

had to add the MAC address of the printer here and it started working. don't uncheck Enable MAC Address Filtering this would open your local network to the internet and hacking